# Trying to edit the order status of an incomplete (pending payment) order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have a situation where I need to change the order status where users don't complete payment.

Basically I can't have orders in pending payment (except for one category of product which I've accounted for in my code)

Actually my code works, however, it's the hook that I need help with.

I've tried using `woocommerce_checkout_order_processed` but this fires too early. It interrupts the checkout process and cancels the order (as woocommerce creates an order and puts it in 'pending payment' immediately and before payment is processed).

I've also tried `woocommerce_thankyou` but this doesn't fire at all when user closes payment window and navigates away from the checkout (but order is created and 'pending').

Here's the code I have with the hook being used

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'tjn_set_cancelled_for_unpaid_orders' );

 function tjn_set_cancelled_for_unpaid_orders( $order_id ) {
 
     $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
     $isVirtual = false;
     $isHidden = false;
 
     foreach ($order->get_items() as $order_item){
       $item = wc_get_product($order_item->get_product_id());
       if ($item->is_virtual()) {
           $isVirtual = true;
       }
       if ($item->get_catalog_visibility() == 'hidden') {
         $isHidden = true;
       }
   }
   if ($isVirtual && !$isHidden) {
     if ($order->has_status('pending')) {
      $order->update_status( 'cancelled' );
     }
     
   }
     
 }
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance!